# Why are there $(2kn+1)^{kn}$ Turing Machines with $k$ symbols and $n$ states?

Tags: turing-machines, combinatorics

I've seen a few references [[1]](http://sodfather.blogspot.com/2006/08/super-simple-turing-machines-and-busy.html), [[2]](http://www.logique.jussieu.fr/~michel/tmi.html), [[3]](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0906.3749.pdf) that say that for a Turing Machine with transition function defined by:

$\delta: Q \times \Gamma \rightarrow Q \times \Gamma \times \{L, R\}$

the number of turing machines with $n$ states and $k$ tape symbols is $(2kn+1)^{kn}$.

However, looking at the definition, shouldn't it be $(2kn)^{kn}$ instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps they are counting the number of Turing machines with *at most* $n$ states. In any case, it's not a big difference. Usually one is only interested in an upper bound, and from that perspective there is no difference between the two expressions.

Comment: Thanks, I was just curious as to why there is that difference though.